# Pythonでテキストファイルから負値を含む数字の抽出をしたい

Tags: python, 正規表現

Pythonでテキストファイルの読み込みを行いたいです。

```
Value : ********  -12.345   *****
```

という内容のファイルから、`-12.345` の部分だけを抜き出すにはどうすればよいでしょうか。
ファイルによって　-（マイナス）がついていたりついていなかったりするのですが、ここを一般化した書き方がわかりません。
よい書き方があれば、ご教示いただけますでしょうか。

Comment: いつも同じ桁位置にあるとか、前後に特徴的な文字/文字列があるとか、あるいは場合によってそれらが変わるとか、何らかの法則/規則があるかどうか追記してみてください。それが分からないなら、実際にあるデータの例をなるべく色々なパターンが含まれるように抽出して追記してみてください。あとは、それが何のデータなのか、何に使いたいかといったことも書かれると、実は別の手段とかが考えられるかもしれません。

Comment: たぶん正規表現 (regex) を使うことになるかも。しかしその目的の数字以外にもヒットしてしまうかもしれないので, もう少し詳しい情報が必要です。(例えば `Value: 三丁目 12番地, 12.345, 温度 20度` とかあるなら面倒)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。Value という文字列が使われているのがそれぞれのファイル中でここだけなので、Valueの行をとってくることは容易です。そこから、アスタリスクに囲まれた数字をとってくるにはどうしたらいいのか、、、というところです。

Comment: findallメソッドを使って、Valueという文字列が含まれている行をとってきた結果、上記の質問の状態になって止まってしまっています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> そこから、アスタリスクに囲まれた数字をとってくるにはどうしたらいいのか

`float` に cast する方法があります。

```py
def isFloat(s):
  try:
    float(s)
    return True
  except ValueError:
    return False

lines = [
  'Value : ********  -12.345   *****',
  'Value : ********-12.345*****',
  'Value : ********  -1.2345e-1*****',
  'Value : ********   12.345   *****',
  'Value : ********  +12.345   *****',
  'Value : ********1.*****',
  'Value : ********.5*****',
]

for l in lines:
  print([num.strip() for num in filter(None, l.split('*')) if isFloat(num)])
=>
['-12.345']
['-12.345']
['-1.2345e-1']
['12.345']
['+12.345']
['1.']
['.5']
```

Comment: print([num.strip() for num in filter(isFloat, l.split('*'))]) でいいのではありませんか？

Comment: @lehshell その場合、`isFloat` の呼び出しが14回(`lines[0]`の場合)になってしまうのです。`filter(None, ...)` であれば2回で済みます。

Comment: ご説明ありがとうございます。理解できました。

Comment: すみません、もう一点お教えください。
print([num.strip() for num in l.split('*') if num and isFloat(num)])
とするよりメリットあるのでしょうか？

Comment: 10万回ループさせて timeit で実行時間を測ると `filter` 版の方が僅かに速い(4ms)のですが、まぁ、メリットではないですね。

Comment: time.perf_counter_ns() で測定すると両方とも 3.5ms 程度です。
filter 版  3.35, 3.31, 3.71, 3.57, 3.50 ms
non filter 版  3.72, 3.56, 3.43, 3.40, 3.78 ms
print を除いて list を返す関数にして測定すると両方とも 20μs 程度でした。
filter 版  20.3, 21.6, 21.0, 23.8, 19.6 μs
non filter 版  19.8, 18.9, 24.3, 18.7, 18.7 μs
そのまま測定した場合は、ほとんどが print 時間ですね。

Answer (score 1):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-↲

import re
# *** number *** 
# ** で囲われた数字が１つあるという前提
# 全角数字は含めない場合

d = """
Value : *** ー１０ ***
Value : ** -100 -200 -201.1 ***
Value : ***** -１０００ ***
Value : ******** -12.345 *****
Value : ******** 12.345 *****
Value : ******** -112.345 *****
Value : ******** -12.345 *****
"""

pattern = r'\*+ ((-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)|(-[0-9]+\.)|(-[0-9]+)) \*+'

matchs = re.finditer(pattern, d)
for match in matchs:
    print(match.groups()[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

文字列の途中にほかに数字が入っていないと仮定するなら, こんな風にできます

```py
import re

s = 'Value : ******** -12.345 *****'
m = re.search(r'-?[\d\.]+', s)
if m:
    print(f'数値は {m[0]}')
```

もし何度も使うようなら高速化のためにこんな風に

```py
import re

num = re.compile(r'-?[\d\.]+')

# 何度も処理を行う部分
m = num.search(s)
if m:
    print(f'数値は {m[0]}')
```

(注意)
[re --- 正規表現操作](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html) の「任意の Unicode 10 進数字」と小数点, の連続にマッチさせていますが, 文字列の中に全角の数字とか入ってるとヒットするはずなので, 文字列データによってはこれではマズイかも

---

(注意点についての補足 追記)
なので状況に応じて `re.ASCII`指定する必要があるかもしれません

```py
import re

num = re.compile(r'-?[\d\.]+', re.ASCII)
s = 'Value : ******** -1１2.345 *****'

m = num.search(s)
if m:
    v = float(m[0])
    print(f'数値は {m[0]} ({v})') # 数値は -1 (-1.0)
```

---

(更に追記)
隠し文字ではなく本当に `'*'` が入っているだけならこんな方法も

```py
s = 'Value : ******** -1１2.345 *****'

prefix = 'Value : '

if s.startswith(prefix):
    s = s[len(prefix):]
v = s.strip('*')
print(float(v))
```

Python3.9以降なら `removeprefix()`が利用できるのでもっと短く書くことも可能

```py
v = s.removeprefix(prefix).strip('* ')
print(float(v))
```